# Strophe to be used in Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, xmpp, strophe

i am building a website intended for mobile devices. I am using JQuery mobile for most of the UI/UX.

I am currently having difficulties integrating stropheJS so that i can run the website properly in mobile devices.

```
$(document).bind('connect', function (ev, data) {
    //Groupie.connection = new Strophe.Connection('http://chat.local/http-bind');

    Groupie.connection.connect(
        data.jid, data.password,
        function (status) {
            alert('Initializing');
            if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
                $(".chat").hide();
                $("#inner_chat").show();
                $(document).trigger('connected');
            } else if (status === Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
                $(document).trigger('disconnected');
            }else{
                alert('Nothing Happens...');
            }
        });
});
```

Above is a simple snippet of the code shows if Strophe is successfully connected it will show the chat interface.

When i test the code above using desktop browser, everything went smooth. Strophe can log into the room, list all participants and best of all chat with other.

However, things get messy when i try it using browser in mobile devices. I always get the "Nothing happens" alert message indicating the Strophe is neither CONNECTED nor DISCONNECTED.

Does anyone know why this is happening? If only there is an app like firebug for mobile.

Comment: Are you sure that your XMPP server is reachable from mobile? That's certainly one way to get Strophe in undefined status.

Answer (score 1):

I guess i would have to answer my own question.

My implementation of xmpp (openfire) is heavily rely on flxhr (as a way around navigating the CORS or Cross Domain Request). What flxhr does is silently injecting flash object to the DOM document, which means devices that do not have flash plugin installed would not be able to process this.

As most of us might aware of, most mobile devices are no longer has or supporting flash. Therefore using flxhr is not a viable option.

I stumble upon this plugins [OpenFire Websocket](https://code.google.com/p/openfire-websockets/) which gives exactly what i want. At the moment i am still wrapping my head around this thing.

One way to test if your version of OpenFire has this plugin or not is by simply pointing your browser to

[your-domain-dot-whatever]:7070/ws (By default the suffix would be "ws" but this could be change by login into your openfire control panel and go to the websocket tab.

Sadly there are little documentation or example on how to implement this. So if anyone has a great reference on this please share it.

Cheers

Comment: Hi, did you finished your app? I am doing a app which has very similar requirement as you mentioned. I am new for XMPP. Did you find some way or framework to do XMPP things via websocket? Did strophe must use flxhr?

Comment: @yuyue007 Yes i finished the apps. I ended up using (and heavily modified) Candy IO (you could google candy XMPP for that matter). If you are familiar with JavaScript, there shouldn't be a problem.

However, due to the nature of mobile devices it seems impractical to develop web based chat application for mobile. Mobile devices will have certain timeout to automatically turn-off its service (i.e. turning of screen, suspending any network connectivity and such) after certain period of time.

This will have great impact on the user experience as they will have to re-connect when screen is off.

Comment: @yuyue007 (cont'd) And it is very difficult to mitigate this situation as your chat app would then be run from browser.

Comment: @yuyue007 How you entered in a room for Chat ? I have tried groupie example got the code from here `https://github.com/metajack/profxmpp`. One to One chat is okay and running perfectly I configured open fire. But whe I tried chap 8 example it just always disconnecting . Here are details for my question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907406/strophe-groupie-example-chp-8-always-disconnecting`.